# WP7 IE - CSS modal popup: Taps/Clicks go through overlay div and trigger links that should be invisible

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I am making a HTML/CSS and jQuery-based file manager aimed at mobile devices. Part of it involves the use of CSS=based modal dialog boxes for various file operations (copy, delete etc.).

I achieve the modal dialog behaviour like this:

```
<div id="overlay">
     <div id="modalBoxControls"><a href="#" id="modalBoxClose">[close]</a></div>
     <div id="modalBox">
          <div id="modalBoxContent"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
#overlay {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 z-index: 1000;
 background: ([semi-transparent png]);
 display: none;
}
#modalBox {
width: 80%;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 0px auto;
opacity: 1;
}
```

I use jQuery to show and hide it by calling `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` on the `overlay` element.

So far so good - this works great in all the browsers on my dev machine.

However, when testing on my WP7 (Samsung Omnia 7), a rather bizarre thing happens. The modal dialog shows up fine, the page behind it is blacked out. But clicks (or taps) go through the `#overlay` and activate anything behind it, even though it totally covers up everything behind and it's z-index is 1000.

I also tested this with the well-known "Lightview" plugin from Nick Stakenburg (a well-tested and refined piece of code) and found the same behaviour on IE on WP7.

So it seems like this could be a bug with the browser itself.

Does anyone know any solution for this?

**Edit - jsFiddle with example of problem**

So, check this out in your WP7 device and see how the files can still be clicked even when there is an overlay over the top of them: http://jsfiddle.net/michaelbromley/CHU76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that there may be no "proper" solution to this problem (hey, 24 hours is a long time on SO!), so I have come up with my own hack solution:

I when the modal dialog box is opened, I simultaneously set the "visibility" CSS property of all the elements "behind" the overlay (i.e. links and anything else that would otherwise erroneously respond to taps/clicks) to "hidden" (by using jQuery's `.css()` function). This means that the page layout is not affected, and that there is now nothing there to be clicked on.

As I said, this is a bit of a hack and will not be suitable for everyone who runs into this problem. However, it works well for me.

Code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michaelbromley/CHU76/1/

Answer (score 1):

If by "activate anything behind it" means input controls like text input then I had the same issue. To be honesty I don't know a good solution. My workaround was disabling input controls during popup is showed and then activating them back by removing disabled attribute. The problem seems not to be related to jqmobile, but supposed to be a general behavior.

Comment: Well, I meant `<a>` tags are clickable, but I would imagine that if I had form fields there, they would also be 'input-able' too. So sounds like the same issue there. I might have to try temporarily making the background invisible just for IE on WP7 at least.
Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is clearly a bug in Window Phone 7 and it is not even fixed in Windows Phone 10.
I will report this bug to Microsoft and hopefully it will be fixed.