# Why is a link anchor within div with lower z-index clickable in IE on windows phone 7?

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, anchor, z-index

I have 2 absolute positioned divs above each other.

- The div with z-index:0; contains the navigation of the website.
- The div with z-index:1; is positioned on top of the other div, making the navigation not visable.

The menu items are still clickable when the div is not visable, how is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you have `pointer-events: none;` on the top div or something. Alternatively, that could be the way to fix it (set `pointer-events: none;` on the div with `z-index: 0;`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to apply your suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094097/wp7-ie-css-modal-popup-taps-clicks-go-through-overlay-div-and-trigger-links-t

Answer (score 1):

Does the div with z-index 1 have a background?

By default, background-colors are set to "transparent" but IE reads them as invisible when z-indexed. This means that if your div with `z-index: 1` doesn't have a background, IE basically pretends it isn't there.

You can hack this by setting the background to some phony url like,

```
background: url(not_a.gif)
```

as I found from this [this forum](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67762-Simple-Controls-Internet-Explorer-9-Z-Index-issue). The same solution is also shown in a [another example](http://www.icreatestuff.co.uk/index.php/blog/article/ie9-z-index-stacking-problem-or-something-stranger) involving links.