# Click on absolute DIV in Windows mobile firing click on underlying elements

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a overlay DIV with absolute position width height and width 100%. But when I click on the overlay DIV, click is happening on underlying elements of overlay DIV. Overlay DIV style is like below

```
 .overlayDIV{
     absolute : absolute;
     height : 100%;
     width : 100%;  
     z-index : 1234;       
 }
```

How can I prevent that...? This problem exists only in Windows mobile

Comment: set the overlay index to have a higher z-index.

Comment: @kennypu Yes I had set, but still no grace..

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094097/wp7-ie-css-modal-popup-taps-clicks-go-through-overlay-div-and-trigger-links-t/22657307#22657307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of the event:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('divId').onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#divId').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also if you have some handlers on mousedown down the page you need to cancel mousedown from your overlay div (same code but for mousedown handler).

Comment: @Reddy I have updated the answer. You may have some mousedown functionality on the underlying elements.

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this in IE 10 but not 11, my solution was to add the following CSS rule to the overlay:

```
background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```